# Flutter: getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() returns null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() is returning null. I can't figure out why....

```
getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((directory) {
  print(_directory);
  _directory = directory;
});
```

null is printed to the console...

Do I need to register something or ask for permissions?

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Inside your manifest add like this :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.yyy">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
</manifest>
```

and also need Runtime Request Permission, by using simple_permissions package. Refer below code:

```
    import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';

    PermissionStatus permissionResult = await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission. WriteExternalStorage);
    if (permissionResult == PermissionStatus.authorized){
      // code of read or write file in external storage (SD card)
      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((directory) {
        print(_directory);
        _directory = directory;
     });
    }
```

[Refer to this tutorial for learning more about using runtime permission in flutter.](https://medium.com/@sadabwasim/flutter-runtime-permission-d82461ff926c)

Comment: Thank you :) But following this tutorial saved my problem without using permissions (https://youtu.be/Hqqz2BaPUis)

Answer (score 1):

if you added the android permission as suggested and it still does not work try adding `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` as the very first thing in your `main` function. this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my side, I replace `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` with `getTemporaryDirectory`, it works, I guess the first one no error catching!

Answer (score 0):

On AndroidManifest.xml, inside the

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="xxx.yyyy.zzz.www">
...
</manifest>
```

tag, put the following lines to grant permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```